# How to use React Component inside old html/js/jQuery Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a jQuery based web application. Now I just need to create a react component and render it inside the existing application. this I can achieve using  react cdn links. But the concern now I wanna use third party library data table component inside this project, is that possible?

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: I think you are asking specifically about 3p react components.  yes you can use these, as long as you can find a distro, that you can include in your page - i.e. their minified javascript etc.

Comment: Or are you asking, if you can use 3p html/jquery components inside your react app?  yes you can, but you may need to wrap them in a react component.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool: https://mohebifar.github.io/vidact/
It converts react components to vanillaJS

Comment: Thanks for quick response bro, will try it once

Comment: np, let me know if it helped

Comment: no, it is unable to convert import statements which Im expecting to work